# NB 15 Error de conexionjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans, jdbc

Muy buenas, no puedo lograr establecer la conexión con la base de datos. Uso NB 15 y la base es con sqlite para lo que descargue el jar 3.14.2.1 y lo añadí a la librería  siguiendo instrucciones de que así debería hacerse pero me responde lo del título y ya no sé por dónde ir. Agradezco si alguien me puede explicar que estoy haciendo mal.
Un saludo.

este es el proyecto que estoy trabajando :

```js
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package examenprodmain.productos2;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

/**
 *
 * @author piero
 */
public class ConexionDB {
    String strConexionDB="jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/piero/OneDrive/Documentos/DB/DBProductos.s3db";
    Connection conn= null;
    
    public ConexionDB(){
        try {
             Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
             conn=DriverManager.getConnection(strConexionDB);
             
             System.out.println("Coenxion establecida");
             
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
                System.out.println("Error de conexion"+e);
                
            }
        }
    
}
```